# Create a button inside email

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm trying to create a button or action bar inside this code

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    Intent emailIntent=Intent.makeMainSelectorActivity(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, Intent.CATEGORY_APP_EMAIL );
    emailIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(emailIntent);
```

so when the user login into his email there is a button appear , is that possible?

Comment: You want to show a button in other email app? what kind of button? If its send button then probably it will be there

Comment: I mean create button inside email body to do some action that I want

Comment: No you cannot do that.

Comment: so if I want to add some features to the email , how can I do that ? is there's any way. it's not necessary a button

Comment: What the features refer to?

Comment: I want to convert the text message to voice ,so I have to create a control bar for reading ,stop reading and slow, fast the rate of the read

Comment: You need to create your own app for that.